# click event is not working in angular 4 when sending html code from component method

Tags: javascript, angular

If I want to send the data from a method to that html page of the component.
Please take templateUrl and then in a method send that click  function html code and please tell me how to make it work.
We must send the html code through a method as shown below.
Because in my case the code will be changing based on some condition in backend and I am sending that html code through the method.

```
test.component.ts
-----------
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'test',
 templateUrl: `test.html`
})
export class TestComponent {
  msg = "";
  clickMsg = "";
  nCnt: number = 0;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.createMsg();
  }

  clickMe() {
      this.nCnt = this.nCnt + 1;
      this.clickMsg = "Clicked: " + this.nCnt;
  }

createMsg(){
 this.msg=`<button (click)="clickMe()">Click</button>
    <br/> <p><strong>{{clickMsg }}</strong></p>`;
}
}

test.html
----------
<div> {{ msg }} </div>
```

This is my requirement and am unable to get that click event.
Please try the above code and let me know.
please help me,Waiting for your working demo ansers.

Comment: why can't you do it with simple ngIf it will be much simpler rather than trying to modify the DOM after init

Comment: Hi Rahul ,In my case the html code will be changing based on some condition in backend and I am sending that html code through the method.

Comment: then also ngIf else can do the job right what you check in component to render the html can be done is template why manipulate DOM when it can be done normally

Comment: No at the time of loading the page only I need to send the conditional data.It the reason why I am trying to add the html code In backend based on the condition.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
<div [innerHTML]="msg"></div>
```

and change your msg to

```
this.msg='<button (click)="clickMe()">Click</button>
    <br/> <p><strong>{{clickMsg }}</strong></p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

@Vishal here is solution for you question with example for Angular 4.

```
import {Compiler, Component, Input, NgModule, NgModuleFactory, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-content-loader',
  template: '<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="dynamicComponent;ngModuleFactory: dynamicModule;"></ng-container>'
})
export class DynamicContentLoaderComponent implements OnInit {

  dynamicComponent;
  dynamicModule: NgModuleFactory<any>;

  @Input()
  text: string;

  constructor(private compiler: Compiler) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dynamicComponent = this.createNewComponent(this.text);
    this.dynamicModule = this.compiler.compileModuleSync(this.createComponentModule(this.dynamicComponent));
  }

  protected createComponentModule(componentType: any) {
    @NgModule({
      imports: [],
      declarations: [
        componentType
      ],
      entryComponents: [componentType]
    })
    class RuntimeComponentModule {
    }
    // a module for just this Type
    return RuntimeComponentModule;
  }

  protected createNewComponent(text: string) {
    let template = text;

    @Component({
      selector: 'dynamic-component',
      template: template
    })
    class DynamicComponent implements OnInit {
      text: any;

      ngOnInit() {
        this.text = text;
      }

      getUserId(id) {
        console.log(id);
        console.log('id');
      }
    }
    return DynamicComponent;
  }
}
```

How to Use

1) In your html file

```
<app-dynamic-content-loader [text]="inputText2"></app-dynamic-content-loader>
```

2) in your ts file

```
inputText2 = '<a (click)="getUserId(111)" style="color: #2196f3">@facebook</a> <span>&nbsp;<a (click)="getUserId(111)" style="color: #2196f3">@facebook</a> <span>&nbsp;</span></span>';
```

Comment: I am getting error : No template specified for component DynamicComponent.  Have you tested it before ??